# What Does the "Structure" in VB.NET Mean?

Tags: vb.net

I was reading a VB.NET code and there was the following:

```
Structure  MyRecord
   "some code here"
End Structure
```

Then he use it as if it is a Class. So, what is the "Structure" ??

IS it only in .NET ,or there are similar things in other language??

Something else,in the same code there are:

```
Dim num As integer=FreeFile()
```

what does that mean?,can we put a function in a variable in VB?

If we can, then what does that mean??

Comment: You probably got a down vote because you asked two questions, because you should ask only one, unless you have a question that is dependent on another.

Comment: If you want to get to know the basic elements of a programming language, you should buy a book about it, have a look into the manuals or find some beginners tutorial on the web. By the way, googling "structure vb.net" will find you a fine answer at the first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1
A structure is used to define a value type, just as a class is used to define a reference type. However, a structure is more complicated to implement correctly than a class, so you should stick to classes until you really need to implement a value type. The structure in the example should probably also be implemented as a class instead.

There are structures in other languages, but they may be handled differently. In C++ for example a structure is used to define a type, and the usage determines if it's a value type or a reference type.

2
Yes, you can put a reference to a function (i.e. a delegate) in a variable, but that's not what that code does. It simply calls the function and puts the return value in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Via [startVBdotnet.com](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/oop/structure.aspx):

> Structures can be defined as a tool
>   for handling a group of logically
>   related data items. They are
>   user-defined and provide a method for
>   packing together data of different
>   types. Structures are very similar to
>   Classes. Like Classes, they too can
>   contain members such as fields and
>   methods. The main difference between
>   classes and structures is, classes are
>   reference types and structures are
>   value types. In practical terms,
>   structures are used for smaller
>   lightweight objects that do not
>   persist for long and classes are used
>   for larger objects that are expected
>   to exist in memory for long periods.
>   We declare a structure in Visual Basic
>   .NET with the Structure keyword.

Generally, I would suggest implementing a class instead of a structure.  This way you can use inheritance and general [Object Oriented Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_oriented_design) later, if needed.